# Fitting Elements of the TabLayout into Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I have an Activity in my Android Application that contains a TabLayout to switch between different fragments. I implemented a custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter to insert my columns and initialize it within my Activity with using tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager) method.

My problem is that, in case of I use TabLayout.MODE_FIXED within my tabLayout I end up with one of the elements, i.e Discussions, as distorted as in the picture below:

[image: tabLayout with TabLayout.MODE_FIXED]

And on the other case if I use TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE, I end up with all of the predefined elements of my tabLayout as shrinked into left corner of the application with plenty of empty space regardless of which gravity I specify as such:

[image: tabLayout with TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE]

The result I am trying to obtain is either:

1) TabLayout in Fixed Mode that has no two liner or overlapping elements, or;

2) TabLayout in Scrollable Mode that at least cover all empty space available and/or cover more than given space as it will be acceptable as long as User can scroll within TabLayout to view and access invisible tabs.

Related source and resource codes are given below. If any case of more information are needed, please let me know.

My activity code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import swe574.boun.edu.androidproject.adapters.GroupTabPagerAdapter;

public class GroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private GroupTabPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private List<String> mTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        mTitles.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Home" , "Meetings" , "Discussions" , "Notes"}));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new GroupTabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mTitles, 4);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_group, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

My GroupTabPagerAdapter code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

import swe574.boun.edu.androidproject.fragments.DiscussionFragment;
import swe574.boun.edu.androidproject.fragments.GroupHomeFragment;
import swe574.boun.edu.androidproject.fragments.MeetingFragment;
import swe574.boun.edu.androidproject.fragments.NoteFragment;

public class GroupTabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<String> mTitles;
    private int mNumOfTabs;

    public GroupTabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> mTitles, int mNumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mTitles = mTitles;
        this.mNumOfTabs = mNumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new GroupHomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new MeetingFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new DiscussionFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new NoteFragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTitles.get(position);
    }


}
```

My Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="swe574.boun.edu.androidproject.GroupActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this problem with extending TabLayout in a custom class and overriding the onMeasure method with this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    try {
        if (getTabCount() == 0){
            return;
        }
        Field field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mTabMinWidth");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, (int) (getMeasuredWidth() / (float) getTabCount()) * 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```